# PyCharm has no shortcut or launcher

Tags: linux, desktop-shortcuts

After installing PyCharm on Pop! OS (by extracting the download) there is no easy way to run the program.

I have probably installed it in `my Documents` folder. Not sure what the convention is.

To run PyCharm I need to go to the folder `pycharm-community-2019.2.4/bin`, open terminal and run

```
./pycharm.sh
```

Any way to make my life easier?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use main menu. There is `Tools` -> `Create Desktop Entry`. It might require root permissions.

Answer (score 6):

Create the file `~/.local/share/applications/pycharm.desktop`.

Add to the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Pycharm
Comment=Pycharm
Exec=/path/to/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/pycharm/pycharm.png
StartupNotify=true
```

Now it will run when you searh for it in the dash.

Answer (score 4):

What I had to do since Tools -> Create Desktop Entry wasn't available was:

Open up PyCharm to the Welcome to PyCharm screen (you may have to exit your project if it loads instead) then click on configure at the bottom (gear icon), and select the dropdown for "Create Desktop Entry" there instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am working with terminal a lot, I don't mind it is not on my desktop. If you are the same, can try add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias pycharm="$HOME/pycharm-community-2019.2.4/bin/pycharm.sh"
```

Then from terminal, you can just type `pycharm` to launch it. You should adjust the path used in the alias to point to the `pycharm.sh` executable on your system.

Comment: That didn't work for some reason. :/
I tried a few different aliases but it doesn't find the command.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else could not find where this tools menu is, please see the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in this path

```
/snap/pycharm-community/256/snap/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
```