# How to create pycharm shortcut on Kali Linux with the newest version?

Tags: kali-linux, desktop-shortcuts

I just downloaded `pycharm` 2020.3.3 and run the command `bash pycharm.sh` and everything runs smoothly. But with newest version main menu UI, it doesn't have the configure option, it only has the gear icon at the bottom and in its drop down menu. It also doesn't have the option create a desktop so anyone know how I can create a desktop shortcut for `pycharm` 2020.3.3 on Kali Linux?

I have tried to solve this with some of the step that is listed here: [PyCharm has no shortcut or launcher](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571135/pycharm-has-no-shortcut-or-launcher) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Why do you need to run an IDE on Kali Linux? It's for penetration testing, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Tools menu. From the drop-down list you will find Create Desktop Entry.